# Woocommerce Analytics and Status widget not reporting net sales or orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I recently did an woocommerce update to woocommerce 7.8 since I have noticed that the woocommerce status widget and analytics are not reporting net sales or orders even prior to the update. If I go to previous months its not 0.

Does anyone how to fix this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c94M3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYoNP.png)